# c3p0 Connection Provider not set

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, c3p0

I am using spring an Hibernate and here is the Hibernate.properties
The problem is the Connection provider is not changing to c3p0ConnectionProvider even though there are c3p0 settings.THey are just loaded and nothing seems to be done with them.

```
    hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin = true
hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout = 0
hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement=5
hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=3000
hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize=10
hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=300
hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize=50
hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements=100
hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize=5
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionsOnCheckout=true
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
            main INFO [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    main INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@70074fd2: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu May 24 15:39:51 MDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/core-data-annotation-context.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/core-data-datasource-context.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/core-profile-datasource-context.xml]
    main INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@70074fd2]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f41eb55
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f41eb55: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,pagingProviderHibernate,daoEager,dao,coreDataResourceLocator,cachingService,randomUtilService,randomWordGenerationService,placeHolderResolver,logsDbDao,subsetDbDao,profilesdbDao,resourceProfileLoaderNew,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory,infobutton-service,dataSource,sessionFactory,hibernateTemplate,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,subsetlogDao,logDao,profiledataSource,profilesessionFactory,profilehibernateTemplate,profiletransactionManager,profilesDao,pDao]; root of factory hierarchy
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource-mysql.properties]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate.properties]
    main INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource-mysql.properties]
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version] - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements=100, hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=300, hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=3000, hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=true, hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement=5, hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize=10, hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize=50, hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize=5, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate, hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionsOnCheckout=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout=0}
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - Bytecode provider name : javassist
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - Binding entity from annotated class: com.asd.subsetdb.domain.Logs
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - Bind entity com.asd.subsetdb.domain.Logs on table logs
    main INFO [org.hibernate.validator.Version] - Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA
    main INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.search.Version] - Hibernate Search 3.4.2.Final
```

> **main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] - Initializing connection provider:
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider**

```
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.0.77
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.17 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
    main INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    main INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC batch size: 15
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Scrollable result sets: enabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Connection release mode: auto
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Default batch fetch size: 1
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query language substitutions: {}
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Second-level cache: enabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query cache: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Echoing all SQL to stdout
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Statistics: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Default entity-mode: pojo
    main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Named query checking : enabled
    main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - building session factory
    main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
    main INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] - Running schema validator
    main INFO [org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheConfigurator] - setting defaultElementAttributes to [ IS_LATERAL = true, IS_SPOOL = true, IS_REMOTE = true, IS_ETERNAL = false, MaxLifeSeconds = 7200, IdleTime = 1800, CreateTime = 1337895600422, LastAccessTime = 1337895600422, getTimeToLiveSeconds() = 7199, createTime = 1337895600422 ]
```

Comment: In Hibernate.properties , ther first two lines are picked up (    hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate) but not the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding this to the context/persistence.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> 
  <property name="driverClass"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property> 
  <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost XXX</value>    

 </property> 
  <property name="user"><value>zzz</value></property> 
  <property name="password"><value>xxx</value></property> 
</bean>
```

I am still not sure why it did not work without **com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource**.

Comment: Because Spring is apparently setting the connection provider on your behalf: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider, that is a Spring class.

Comment: Yes.But even after explicitly mentioning the connection provider to be c3p0 , it still was not picking that up.